# Matlab's Imshowpair function

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to run MatLab's `imshowpair` function that is a part of the Image Processing Toolbox. I have the following versions of Matlab and Image Processing Toolbox installed:

> MATLAB Version: 8.4(R2014b)
>
> Image Processing Toolbox (R2014b)

Code:

```
A = imread('path/to/image/A');
B = imread('path/to/image/B');

figure;
imshowpair( A, B );
```

Error:

> Undefined function 'imshowpair' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

I've converted the images to doubles as well, but it seems like no matter which type I convert to it still throws the same error, but with a different type in the message.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions? [This link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html#inputarg_A) says at the very bottom that the function was introduced in R2012a, so I would assume I'm good on the versions.

Comment: Have you tried `help imshowpair`? Are you sure you have Image Processing Toolbox installed? You can check manually; imshowpair specifically should be in `[MATLAB folder]\toolbox\images\imuitools\imshowpair.m`.

Comment: What does `which imshowpair` return?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies gordon and horchler. I really appreciate your help. After looking around more I found out that the Image Processing Toolbox was installed, but the license was for a different user (a previous user of the machine). The license needed to be transferred. I apologize for not mentioning that it was a repurposed machine.  I hadn't even thought about the user specific licensing scene at the time of asking.

I had used `ver` to show that Image Processing Toolbox was installed and `license('inuse')` which showed that the license was not in use for me.